# Finding the current academic year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want determine if a date is within the current academic year. In order to do that, I've written a function to determine the current academic year. Is there a better way to do this?

```
# returns start and end date of current academic year
    def academic_year
         # assumption: an academic year is from sept 1st untill sept 1st
        start_date = Date.parse "#{Time.current.year}-09-01"
        end_date   = Date.parse "#{Time.current.year+1}-09-01"

        if Date.today < start_date
            start_date = Date.parse "#{Time.current.year-1}-09-01"
            end_date   = Date.parse "#{Time.current.year}-09-01"
        end

        {start: start_date, end: end_date}
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby you would use [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F)

```
# see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html
start = Date.current.change(month: 9, day: 1)
academic_year = start..start.advance(years: 1)

academic_year.cover?(Date.current.change(month: 6, day: 15)) # false
academic_year.cover?(Date.current.change(month: 10, day: 2).advance(years: 2)) # false
academic_year.cover?(Date.current.change(month: 10, day: 2)) # true
```

But usually you should be querying by date in the database in which case you pass a range to `.where` to create a BETWEEN query:

```
Order.where(placed: 2.years.ago..Time.current)
# SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."placed" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 LIMIT $3
```

Comment: PS. Don't use `Date.parse` unless you are actually dealing with string input. Ruby is an object oriented language and there is always a better way to do things that does not involve string manipulation. Like for example `Date.new(Date.current.year, 9, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we came up with. Bit less readable I guess.

```
def academic_year
  start = (Date.today.month >= 9) ? Date.civil(Date.today.year, 9, 1) : Date.civil(Date.today.year - 1, 9, 1)

  {start: start, end: 1.year.since(start)}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that the school year starts on: `1.9.2023` and ends on `30.6.2024` we can write these classes where return current school/academic year, something like `2023/2024`.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module SchoolYears
  class ByActualDate
    prepend SimpleCommand

    def initialize(date = nil)
      @date = date.presence || Date.current
    end

    def call
      school_year
    end

    private

    attr_reader :date

    def school_year
      result = if minus_one_months.include?(current_month)
                 [date.advance(years: -1).year, date.year]
               else
                 [date.year, date.advance(years: 1).year]
               end

      result.join('/')
    end

    def current_month
      date.month
    end

    def minus_one_months
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    end
  end
end
```

and add some tests:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'test_helper'

module SchoolYears
  class ByActualDateTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    setup do
      @service = ::SchoolYears::ByActualDate
    end

    describe '#call' do
      test '2023/2024' do
        assert_equal '2023/2024', @service.call(Date.new(2024, 1, 1)).result
        assert_equal '2023/2024', @service.call(Date.new(2024, 2, 1)).result
        assert_equal '2023/2024', @service.call(Date.new(2024, 3, 15)).result
        assert_equal '2023/2024', @service.call(Date.new(2024, 6, 1)).result
        assert_equal '2023/2024', @service.call(Date.new(2024, 6, 30)).result
      end

      test '2024/2025' do
        assert_equal '2024/2025', @service.call(Date.new(2024, 7, 1)).result
        assert_equal '2024/2025', @service.call(Date.new(2024, 8, 1)).result
        assert_equal '2024/2025', @service.call(Date.new(2024, 9, 1)).result
        assert_equal '2024/2025', @service.call(Date.new(2024, 10, 15)).result
        assert_equal '2024/2025', @service.call(Date.new(2024, 11, 1)).result
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Result:

```
# Running tests with run options --seed 33702:

..

Finished tests in 0.418755s, 4.7761 tests/s, 23.8803 assertions/s.


2 tests, 10 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```